# How to send a BuddyPress user a notification on a plugin event?

Tags: buddypress, notifications

Done a bit of searching and cant really find the answer.

Looking for idea on how I send a user an admin bar notification in BuddyPress after a certain event is actioned in a plugin I'm building?

BP Version - 1.6.4, Wordpress Version - 3.5.1

Comment: Starting points in [BP forums](http://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-create-a-notification/) and in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15442351/1287812).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to setup component for this:

```
function notifier_setup_globals() {
    global $bp, $current_blog;
    $bp->notifier = new stdClass();
    $bp->notifier->id = 'notifier';
    $bp->notifier->slug = 'notifier';
    $bp->notifier->notification_callback = 'bp_notifier_format_notifications';//this is a function which gets notifications
    $bp->active_components[$bp->notifier->id] = $bp->notifier->id;

    do_action( 'notifier_setup_globals' );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_globals', 'notifier_setup_globals' );
```

To add notifications call something like this inside your action:

`bp_core_add_notification( $item_id, $user_id, $component_name, $component_action, $secondary_item_id = 0, $date_notified = false, $is_new = 1 ) ;`

where `$component_name` in this case is `notifier`.

for farther reading: http://demo.myndconsulting.com/documentation/notification-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Each BuddyPress component has a `bp-[groups|friends|...]-notifications.php` file.
Look at its functions - they are doing notifications.
Search for their names in BuddyPress plugin folders - and you will find places of how to invoke them.